# PySide2 QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl() Error on macOS Seirra

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyside, qt5.6

I am Following the steps from [PySide2 with Qt5.6](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/08/17/compiling-pyside2/) to install PySide2 on macOS sierra 10.12.2. because installing PySide2 through Home-brew is failing. Building and installing the PySide2 works fine. The problem is while importing the class **QDesktopServices** from **QtGui** into my python project. The main intension is to use the **openUrl()** method of QDesktopServices class in my project. I checked it in it QtWidget class of Qt5 also but it is not present to this class. Is anyone know about how to import it or where it is moved from Qt4 to Qt5 code.**(I am trying to migrate my python project from PySide to PySide2)**

Comment: PySide2 is still beta. You should file an error report with them.